# visual studio 2015 command prompt '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, 64-bit, lzo

I worked on GIS project and i need 64 bit gis lib.And than;

What did i?

- I download lzo-2.10 file.
- I run visual studio 2015 64x command prompt
- cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\lzo-2.10
- ./configure

and ı got some error like that:
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

INSTALL.txt which include lzo-2.10 said that:

> The simplest way to compile this package is:

1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type`
   ./configure' to configure the package for your system.  If you're
    using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might need to type`
   sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying to execute`
   configure' itself.

   Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
    messages telling which features it is checking for.
2. Type `make' to compile the package.
3. Optionally, type `make check' to run any self-tests that come with
    the package.
4. Type `make install' to install the programs and any data files and
    documentation.
5. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
    source code directory by typing `make clean'.  To also remove the
    files that`configure' created (so you can compile the package for
    a different kind of computer), type `make distclean'.  There is
    also a`make maintainer-clean' target, but that is intended mainly
    for the package's developers.  If you use it, you may have to get
    all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
    with the distribution.

But I even couldn't first step. I searched but couldn't fix this situation.pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your GIS library require linux to be build. Given that you use VS2015 I assume you work on Windows instead.

Comment: Dudak Yeap, i work on windows 10 but this library could be build 32 bit before. I have 32 bit lzo2.lib but i want to 64 bit.

Comment: The installation instructions you provided are for Linux and won't work on a Windows OS (unless you use Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Comment: Thnx for helping bro.your suggestion and my research ability are combine than i found solution :)) thnk you so much @michal Dudak

Comment: Glad I could help